# Is it possible to access the arguments from an std::bind object?

Tags: c++, c++11, functor, std-function, stdbind

Please consider the following scenario.

A hypothetical pop-up menu class that displays some actions, and when one of them is selected it will call the passed in action which is in form of an `std::function`:

```
PopupMenu::PopupMenu(std::function<void(RowItem*)> editRowFunction, RowItem *item)
    : _editRowFunction(editRowFunction)
    , _item(item) {
}
```

Then at some point it might call execute:

```
PopupMenu::execute(} {
    _editRowFunction(_item);
}
```

Then I have this other class that's a UI object:

```
class EditorWidget {
    void editRow(RowItem *row) {
        //edit the row
    }
}
```

And here's how I am using all of them:

```
int main() {
    auto item = new RowItem();
    auto editorWidget = new EditorWidget();
    PopupMenu menu(std::bind(&EditorWidget::editRow, editorWidget, item), item);
    menu.execute();
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works. My question is the following:
If I am already passing the argument `item` in `std::bind`, why do I have to pass it again as a second parameter in order to be able to call the bound function with that argument? If I don't, and try to call the function just by itself from `PopupMenu::execute()`, I get a compiler error.

The other way around it is to make the constructor of `PopupMenu` like this:

```
PopupMenu::PopupMenu(std::function<void()> editRowFunction)
    : _editRowFunction(editRowFunction) {}
```

And if I do it that way then I call it this way:

```
PopupMenu::execute() {
_editRowFunction();
}
```

What I don't like about this method is that I can pretty much pass any bound function in the `PopupMenu` constructor and it will be called. But that's not what I want, I want to enforce only a function with a specific signature.

I can also pass a lambda, yes. But let's try to solve it without lambdas.
Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you looked into placeholder arguments?

Comment: @StephenNewell, yes and from what I saw it's not solving my problem. I am binding it to an actual argument, so I don't need to pass a placeholder. I would however want to access that argument in the form of a placeholder, but I don't think it'll work.

Comment: @Scheff, yes sure, but I don't want to use a lambda. The question is why is it not possible to do through `std::bind`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> std::bind(&EditorWidget::editRow, editorWidget, item)
> ```

`std::bind` here is creating a functional object that takes a pointer to a member function `EditorWidget::editRow`, bound to an object `editorWidget`, using the parameter `item`. What you've done is actually fix the parameter to the function `EditorWidget::editRow` with the parameter `item`. So effectively you've created a function object that takes no argument (since you've fixed it), and returns `void`.

There's actually no need for the constructor of `PopupMenu` to have a second parameter of type `RowItem*`. You could change the constructor like so:

```
PopupMenu::PopupMenu(std::function<void()> editRowFunction)
    : _editRowFunction(editRowFunction)
{
}
```

and then call your function object like this:

```
PopupMenu::execute(} {
    _editRowFunction();
}
```

In your current code the parameter `_item` is not being used by the function object you pass into the constructor `PopupMenu`. It satisfies the compiler since `_editRowFunction` is of type `std::function<void(RowItem*)>`.

Here's a simple example to illustrate to the point:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct callable
{
    callable(std::function<void(std::string)> fn) : mFn(fn)
    {}

    std::function<void(std::string)> mFn;

    void Run() { mFn("world"); }
};

struct Foo {
    void print(std::string msg)
    {
        std::cout << msg << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    auto fn = std::bind(&Foo::print, &f, "hello");
    fn();

    callable c(fn);
    c.Run(); //expecting "world" to be printed
}
```

You might expect the output to be:

```
hello
world
```

but actually it's:

```
hello
hello
```

Live [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EcEPzK).

What I could do is change the definition of the function object like this:

```
 auto fn = std::bind(&Foo::print, &f, std::placeholders::_1); //uses a placeholder
```

and I get the expected output. You could do something similar without having to make many changes to your current implementation.

Comment: Is there any way to extract the bound argument from `fn` or `mFn`? And if not, does this mean that `mFn` is not really storing it?

Comment: "You could do something similar without having to make many changes to your current implementation." - I think I'd have to make a lot of changes to my implementation, because I can't pass my `std::bind()` with a placeholder, it's of no use for my example.

Comment: I mean I can pass with `std::placeholders::_1`, but then I'd have to specify the parameter too, like I am doing right now, and then call with that parameter. My goal is not to get the thing to execute, it's more about enforcing a certain type of contract between my API and the consumer, so the consumer won't be able to make a mistake.

Comment: Can I somehow make my constructor require its called to pass in an `std::placeholds::_1` instead of an actual argument?

Comment: @armanali I don't think you even need a second parameter `item` in your constructor since your function object is already bound to your object `item`. Use `std::function<void()>` as I said above. It would make more sense to use a placeholder for a parameter that changes between function calls.

Comment: yes I don't. I just wanted to make the API more restrictive, so they wouldn't be passing just anything through `std::bind`, but it looks like there's no simple way to restrict this unless maybe resorting to templates and other methods.

Comment: @armanali You could just pass in pointers to `EditorWidget` and `RowItem` in the constructor and use them in `PopupMenu::execute`. That way you don't need a `std::function` at all. This will be more restrictive.

Comment: but in that case PopupMenu will have to know about `EditorWidget`, so the solution will be tied to `EditorWidget`, and that in IMO is not good design, because I might have another widget class that wants to perform the editing/deletion through the help of `PopupMenu`.